React Apexchart massive amounts of data in select component decreases performance drastically
React Apexcharts displays multiple charts on my page. I also have a react select dropdown on my page but it decreases the performance of my page.
The React Apexchart contains a large amount of data. The dropdown selection opens, but its perfomance is slow. Why is that?
Changes in the dropdown go through, and the on change modal opens, but this functionality is slow. The dropdown change takes 1 minute to open.
const previousBillingDropdownData = () => {
    setIsDropdownLoading(true);
    getPreviousBillingData()
      .then((res) => {
        let data = [];
        res.map((r) => {
          data.push({
            label: `${moment(r.StartDate).format("DD MMM")} ${"-"} ${moment(
              r.EndDate
            ).format("DD MMM YYYY")}`,
            value: r.Id,
            PlanName: r.PlanName,
            StartDate: r.StartDate,
            EndDate: r.EndDate,
          });
        });
        setPreviousBillingData(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setIsDropdownLoading(false);
      });
  };
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    previousBillingDropdownData();
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    clientDataApi()
      .then((res) => {
        setClientData(res.data);

        getGridData(
          moment()
            .subtract(1, "month")
            .format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
          moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")
        );
        getQueriesChart(
          moment()
            .subtract(1, "month")
            .format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
          moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")
        );
        getActiveUserChart(
          moment()
            .subtract(1, "month")
            .format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
          moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")
        );
        getFeedbackChart(
          moment()
            .subtract(1, "month")
            .format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
          moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")
        );
        getTokenChart(
          moment()
            .subtract(1, "month")
            .format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
          moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")
        );
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []); // Empty dependency array to run only once
 const handlePreviousBillingChange = (val) => {
    setSelectedPreviousBilling(val);
    if (val) {
      setIsOpenBillingPopup(!isOpenBillingPopup);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isOpenBillingPopup === true && selectedPreviousBilling) {
      if (selectRef.current) {
        const dropdownContainer = document.querySelector(`.select2-selection`);
        // Find the selected option by aria-selected="true"
        const selectedOption = dropdownContainer.querySelector(
          '[aria-selected="true"]'
        );
        if (selectedOption) {
          const rect = selectedOption.getBoundingClientRect();
          const modalElement = modalRef.current;
          const viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
          const viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
          if (modalElement) {
            setModalPosition({
              position: "fixed",
              top: `${Math.min(rect.top, viewportHeight - rect.height - 20)}px`, // Align the modal with the top of the selected option
              width: `${Math.min(rect.width, 300)}px`,
              left: `${viewportWidth - rect.width - 300}px`, // Set modal width based on dropdown
              maxHeight: `${viewportHeight - rect.bottom}px`,
              transform: "none",
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "column",
            });
            getGridData(
              selectedPreviousBilling &&
                moment(selectedPreviousBilling.StartDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
              selectedPreviousBilling &&
                moment(selectedPreviousBilling.EndDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
            );
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, [isOpenBillingPopup, selectedPreviousBilling]);

